# JavaScript's Math.random generate same numbers in the loop

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to generate different orders of taxi servise (I'll visualize them on Google Maps using Google Maps API). But I allways get only 2 versions of my route

```
while(index < documentNumber) {
    var random_number = Math.random();
    var randomIndex1 = Math.round(random_number * delta + INDEX_MIN);
    var randomIndex2 = Math.round(INDEX_MAX - random_number * delta);
    ...
}
```

All of these vars a const, delta and INDEX_MAX are equal to 9, INDEX_MIN is equal to 0, so my randomIndex1 and randomIndex2 should be whole in range [0; 9]

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a pseduo-random number in the range [0, 1]. So, depending on the values of `INDEX_MIN`, `INDEX_MAX`, and `delta`, when you apply rounding, you might always get 0 or 1.

Comment: what is `delta`? Is it `INDEX_MAX - INDEX_MIN`?

Comment: Do you really need to use the same random number for both indexes?

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Math.round()` in your above code, depending on the values of `delta`, `INDEX_MIN`, and `INDEX_MAX`, it's quite possible that both numbers you're generating could be a random selection of only `0` or `1` rather than any other numbers.

Comment: They should be whole in range [0; 9], so I must have at least 10 different ways